# How do i access usb device info and explore it using java code?

Tags: java, usb

```
public void showInfo(){
    com.codeminders.hidapi.ClassPathLibraryLoader.loadNativeHIDLibrary();
            HIDManager hidManager = HIDManager.getInstance();
            HIDDeviceInfo[] infos = hidManager.listDevices();
              for (HIDDeviceInfo info : infos) {
                System.out.println("info: " + info.toString());
                }
}
```

i used this method in my code but it occurs an exception on this line

`for(HIDDeviceInfo info : infos){
System.out.println("info: "+info.toString());
}`

Exception is:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at JavaClass.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:23)`

and hidmanager giving null

please help me on this code or any alternate solution thanks

Comment: Are you asking "why do I get a NullPointerException?"? Because the answer to that is "because `hidManager` is null". Or are you asking why `hidManager` is null?

Comment: yeah got NullPointerException because of hidManager is null it's clear but why ? i have attached USB device in my computer but it still throws an exception...

Comment: I have no idea about that HID API (or even what it is; some information might help people find answers); just making a small suggestion for the question.

Comment: You are right immibis actually i am looking to retrieve the info of attached usb devices in my computer i have write the above code but it's not working ... thanks for your interest i ll work on it till i get success... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method:

```
 public void show() {
    System.out.println("File system roots returned by FileSystemView.getFileSystemView():");
    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    File[] roots = fsv.getRoots();
    for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Root: " + roots[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Home directory: " + fsv.getHomeDirectory());

    System.out.println("File system roots returned by File.listRoots():");
    File[] f = File.listRoots();
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        if (fsv.getSystemIcon(f[i]).toString().equals("Removable Disk")) {
            try {
                String myusb = f[i].getPath().toString();
                System.out.println("myusb : " + myusb);
                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new java.io.File(myusb));

            } catch (Exception exxx) {
                exxx.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Drive: " + f[i]);
            System.out.println("Display name: " + fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]));
            System.out.println("Total space: " + f[i].getTotalSpace());
            System.out.println("Usable space: " + f[i].getUsableSpace());
            System.out.println("Type: " + fsv.getSystemIcon(f[i]));
            File[] f1 = f[i].listFiles();
            for (int k = 0; k < f1.length; k++) {
                System.out.println("The All Files are" + f1[k]);
                if ((f1[k]).getName().equals("query.txt")) {
                    System.out.println("The File is" + f1[k]);
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```